# use facebook api to create events for a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create facebook events for a page.

As far as I can tell this requires some **app permissions**. These appear to be used in the code when the facebook login link is created (to obtain a token) and in the setting of the app. how those two permission definitions correspond is unknown, but given the mentions of "app reviews" and similar nonsense, i think the definitions in code are mere fluff and therefore unimportant.

During my research I have discovered, that the event related stuff appears to be connected to the **marketing api** for some reason. I have no interest in creating ads, but the connection between events and marketing is not explained.

Via the Graph api explorer I managed to get the following error while creating an event:

```
(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.
```

I know that the **permissions ads_management and ads_read** are required, but in the app's setting, i cannot select these options and associated help text don't explain the overall process clearly.

Does anyone know what permissions I have to request for an app to create an event and how this is done?

Comment: are you sure that creating events is possible with the api? afaik they turned that off some years ago.

Comment: You need to get specifically approved https://developers.facebook.com/products/official-events-api/ and also the page say they currently are approving new applications.

Comment: Sorry I missed a word. They are currently NOT approving new applications